# Global Administrator / disable having access to the email "open another mailbox..."

Tags: email, permissions, exchange, administrative-privileges

I am global admin on a domain and as the name implies, I have access to all emails and having access to their emails via "open another mailbox..." in exchange.

Now, one thing I noticed is that I am not able to access one specific user's email account as with any other account.  Why is this?

How do I check what permission is missing ?
Also, I am intreeged to know how to do this so that other global admin do not have access to my emails without a verification or something ...

Not hidding anything but would be intresting to know or find out to why is one person not allowing global admins not to gain access to their emails in exchange.

Comment: _How do I check what permission is missing?_ well...you obviously check the permissions tab in your Exchange admin console or via PowerShell.

Comment: I seem not to have all the rights to Exhange sever, nor the powershell .... :/ anyway never mind, is not as easy as I thought it would be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the full access rights of these mailboxes, you could ask your Exchange admin(Or using an Exchange admin account) to check whether your account has the access rights of them with the command “ **Get-MailboxPermission -Identity  -User  | where{$_.AccessRights -eq “FullAccess”} | ft Identity, User, AccessRights -AutoSize** ”.

If your account doesn’t have the “**Full Access**” rights to access other mailboxes, you could run the command to grant the **Full Access** rights to your account “ **Add-MailboxPermission -Identity ” -User  -AccessRights “FullAccess”** “:

[image]

[image]